# THREE.js object removing

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, collada

I have trouble dealing with `Three.js`.

The task is, to make a car that stops at the red light. I have the scene, and the car moving, but I cant change the light, no matter what I try. I created a sphere that represents the light, and a button that should change its color. I want it to call a function, that hides the red light and shows the green one.

However, when i call function:

```
        function removeSphere() {
        scene.remove(sphere2);
        render();}
```

nothing happens. I tried different variants, but i cant edit the sphere in any way.

Could anyone help me with this?

Full code below:

```
<head>
    <title>#16 Three.js - ColladaLoader</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var kamera ="A";
    var delta = 0.01;
    var deltaTmp = 0.01;
     function kameraA() { kamera ="A";}
     function kameraB() { kamera ="B";}
     function kameraStartStop() { 
        if(delta == 0.0) {delta = deltaTmp;}
        else {delta = 0.0;}}
     function kameraPrawoLewo() { 
        delta = -delta;
        deltaTmp = -deltaTmp;}
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div >
     &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
    <button onclick="kameraA();">Kamera 1</button> 
    <button onclick="kameraB();">Kamera B</button>
    <button onclick="kameraStartStop();">Kamera START/STOP</button>
    <button onclick="kameraPrawoLewo();">Kamera PRAWO/LEWO</button>
    &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
    <button onclick="removeSphere();">Remove sphere</button>
    <br />
    </div>

    <script src="js/three.js"></script>                 
    <script src="js/loaders/ColladaLoader.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/Detector.js"></script> 



    <script>

        if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();
        var container;
        var camera, scene, renderer, objects;
        var dae,dae1,dae2;
        var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
        loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;
        var url='obj/auto20.dae';

        loader.load( url, function ( collada ) {
            dae = collada.scene;
            dae.traverse( function ( child ) {
                if ( child instanceof THREE.SkinnedMesh ) {
                    var animation = new THREE.Animation( child, child.geometry.animation );
                    animation.play();
                }
            } );

            dae.scale.x = dae.scale.y = dae.scale.z = 200;
            dae.position.y-=460;
            dae.position.x-=4096;
            dae.position.z+=512;
            dae.updateMatrix();

            dae.traverse( function ( child ) {
                child.castShadow = true;
                child.receiveShadow = false;
            } );            

            init();
            animate();
        } );

        function init() {

            container = document.createElement( 'div' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 40000 );
            camera.position.set( Math.pow(2,13), 1024, 0);

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            scene.add( dae );
            scene.add( dae1 );

            // swiatla

            var light1  = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
            light1.castShadow = true;
            light1.position.set(-2000, 2000, -5000);
            light1.shadowCameraNear = 1; 
            light1.shadowCameraFar = 16000;
            light1.shadowCameraRight   =  10000;
            light1.shadowCameraLeft    = -10000;
            light1.shadowCameraTop     =  10000;
            light1.shadowCameraBottom  = -10000;
        //  light1.shadowCameraVisible = true; 
            scene.add( light1 );

            var geometr = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 100, 32, 32 );
            var materi = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xff0000} );
            var sphere2 = new THREE.Mesh( geometr, materi );
            sphere2.position.set(200, 500, 500);
            scene.add( sphere2 );


        function removeSphere() {
        scene.remove(sphere2);
        render();
        }



            scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xcccccc ) );


            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth -16, window.innerHeight - 64 ); //okno renderowania
            renderer.shadowMapEnabled=true;
            renderer.shadowMapType=THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;

            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );


            scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0xbbddee, -2*1024, 32*1024 );  //mgla (kolor, near, far)



        var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('img/dirt2.jpg');
        texture.repeat.set( 64,32); 
        texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
        texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping; 
        texture.anisotropy = 16; 

        var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture}); 
        var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(Math.pow(2,16), Math.pow(2,15)); 

        for ( var i = 0; i < 2; i ++ ) {
        var plane = new THREE.Mesh( planeGeometry, planeMaterial );
            plane.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2; 
            plane.position.y -= 512;
            plane.position.z = i*(Math.pow(2,15)+1024)-Math.pow(2,14);

            plane.castShadow = false; 
            plane.receiveShadow = true; 

            scene.add( plane ); 
        }   


        var texture_1 = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('img/asfalt4.jpg'); 
        texture_1.repeat.set( 64,1);  
        texture_1.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping; 
        texture_1.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping; 
        texture_1.anisotropy = 16;

        var planeMaterial_1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture_1});
        var planeGeometry_1= new THREE.PlaneGeometry(Math.pow(2,16), 1024);
        var plane_1 = new THREE.Mesh( planeGeometry_1, planeMaterial_1 );
            plane_1.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2; 
            plane_1.position.y -= 512;
            plane_1.position.z += 512;

            plane_1.castShadow = false; 
            plane_1.receiveShadow = true; 

            scene.add( plane_1 );   

        //======================================================================

        var textures = ['img/Desert/north.jpg',
                        'img/Desert/south.jpg',
                        'img/Desert/top.jpg',
                        'img/Desert/bottom.jpg',
                        'img/Desert/west.jpg',
                        'img/Desert/east.jpg'];

        var materials = [];


        for(var i=0;i<textures.length;i++) {
            var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(textures[i]);
            texture.anisotropy = renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
            materials.push( new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture, side: THREE.BackSide}));  
        }                                                                                       

        var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(32*1024,32*1024,32*1024);

        var skyBox = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials )); 

        skyBox.position.y -= 1024;

        scene.add( skyBox );  

        }

        function onWindowResize() {

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth -16, window.innerHeight - 64);
        }

        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            render();
        }


        var a = new THREE.Vector3( 1,2,0 );
        var clock = new THREE.Clock();
        var kat = 0;    


        function render() {
            kat += delta;       

        if (kamera=="A"){
            camera.position.x = Math.cos( kat ) * Math.pow(2,13);
            camera.position.y = 1024;
            camera.position.z = Math.sin( kat ) * Math.pow(2,13);
            camera.lookAt( scene.position );
            }
        else{   
            camera.position.x = 0;
            camera.position.y = 4;
            camera.position.z = 0;

            a.x = Math.cos( kat ) * 8;
            a.y = 2;
            a.z = Math.sin( kat ) * 8;

            camera.lookAt( a );
            }


            dae.position.x  += 16;   
            if (dae.position.x>Math.pow(2,14)) {    
                dae.position.x=-Math.pow(2,14);}    

            THREE.AnimationHandler.update( clock.getDelta() ); 

            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        }




    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Why are you removing the object in the first place? It is faster and simpler to just adjust the value of the `.visible` flag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

When adding the sphere to the scene, set some unique name for the sphere like this:

```
sphere.name = "trololol";
```

Then when you want to remove the sphere from the scene, you can do this:

```
var sphereObject = scene.getObjectByName("trololol");
scene.remove(sphereObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared your `removeSphere` function inside of your `init` function. Try moving the function declaration outside of the `init` function and declaring `sphere2` as a global variable.

```
var sphere2;
function init() {
  ...
}
function removeSphere() {
  scene.remove(sphere2);
  render();
}
```